# No se actualizan mis registros en Sqlite desde mi interfaz en Python

Tags: python, sqlite

Buen dia amigos!!!!
Nuevamente recurro a ustedes, en esta ocasión en la interfaz que sigo haciendo tengo este problema, resulta que de mi base de datos en la tabala price_list estan contenidos estudios clinicos con su precio y el costo de la maquila, (las columnas se llaman: estudios_clinicos, precio y maquila)  entonces, hice un boton para eliminar el cual se hace bien la funcion y actualiza la tabla donde ya no se ve el estudio eliminado, pero en esta ocasion le agregue otro boton para editar el estudio para cuando exista la necesidad de actualizar los precios de los estudios o por completo el nombre del estudio, entonces cuando lo quiero actualizar "segun" me indica el programa que se actualizó mi registro porque le puse un cuadro de dialogo emergente indicando eso, pero no se actualiza ya que lo corroboro en el DBrowser y no pasa nada, quise ver los valores que se teclean en la pantalla de la terminal pero no se observan salen en blanco que estoy haciendo mal???

```
      def run_query_1(self, query, parameters = ()): #Consulta en la tabla de lista de precios
         with sqlite3.connect(self.db_lab) as conn:
              cursor = conn.cursor()
              result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
              conn.commit()
         return result
         # Consulta de datos
         query = 'SELECT * FROM price_list ORDER BY id_folio DESC'
         db_rows = self.run_query_1(query)

      def get_estudios(self): #Obtencion de la lista de precios y desplegada en una tabla

          # Limpiando la tabla
          records = self.tree.get_children()
          for element in records:
          self.tree.delete(element)
          # getting data
          query = 'SELECT * FROM price_list ORDER BY id_folio DESC'
          db_rows = self.run_query_1(query).fetchall()
          # filling data
          for row in db_rows:
              self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[1], values = (row[1], row[2], row[3]))


      def delete_estudios(self):     
          try:
              self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text'][0]
          except IndexError as e:
          messagebox.showinfo('Borrado de estudios', 'Por favor elija un estudio')
          return

          estudios_clinicos = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
          query = 'DELETE FROM price_list WHERE estudios_clinicos = ?'
          self.run_query_1(query, parameters=(estudios_clinicos,))
          messagebox.showinfo('Borrado de estudios', 'Registro Borrado')
          self.get_estudios()

    def edit_estudio(self):

        try:
          self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
          messagebox.showinfo('Editar estudio', 'Por favor elija un estudio')
        return
          estudios_clinicos= self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
          precio = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][1]
          maquila = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][2]

          #Ventana alterna
          self.edit_wind = Toplevel()
          self.edit_wind.title = 'Editar estudio'

          # Estudio anterior
          Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Estudio anterior:').grid(row = 0, column = 1)
          Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = estudios_clinicos), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 0, column = 2)

          # Nuevo Estudio
          Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Nuevo estudio:').grid(row = 1, column = 1)
          self.new_name = Entry(self.edit_wind)
          self.new_name.focus()
          self.new_name.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

          # Precio anterior
          Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Precio anterior:').grid(row = 2, column = 1)
          Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = precio), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 2, column = 2)
          # Nuevo precio
          Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Nuevo precio:').grid(row = 3, column = 1)
          self.new_price= Entry(self.edit_wind)
          self.new_price.grid(row = 3, column = 2)


          # Precio de maquila anterior
          Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Precio maquila anterior:').grid(row = 4, column = 1)
          Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = maquila), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 4, column = 2)
          # Nuevo precio de maquila
          Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Nuevo precio maquila:').grid(row = 5, column = 1)
          self.new_price_maq= Entry(self.edit_wind)
          self.new_price_maq.grid(row = 5, column = 2)


          Button(self.edit_wind, text = 'Actualizar', command = lambda: self.edit_records(self.new_name.get(), estudios_clinicos, self.new_price.get(), precio, self.new_price_maq.get(), maquila)).grid(row = 7, column = 2, sticky = W)
          print(self.new_name.get()) # en esta parte no se ven los datos tecleados por el usuario solo se ve en blanco
          print(self.new_price.get()) # aqui igual
          print(self.new_price_maq.get()) #tambien aqui
          print(estudios_clinicos) #estos si se visualizan
          print(precio)
          print(maquila)       

          self.edit_wind.mainloop()

     def edit_records(self, new_name, estudios_clinicos, new_price, precio, new_price_maq, maquila):
         query = 'UPDATE price_list SET estudios_clinicos = ?, precio = ?, maquila = ? WHERE estudios_clinicos = ? AND precio = ? AND maquila = ?'
         parameters = (new_name, estudios_clinicos, new_price, precio, new_price_maq, maquila)
         self.run_query_1(query, parameters)
         self.edit_wind.destroy()
         messagebox.showinfo('Actualizar estudio', 'El estudio ha quedado actualizado') #aqui es donde me indica que se editó correctamente


         self.get_estudios()
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a encontrar el problema!!!
gracias 
Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se actualizan porque pasa mal los parámetros a la query. La query es:

```
UPDATE price_list
SET estudios_clinicos = ?,
    precio = ?,
    maquila = ?
WHERE estudios_clinicos = ?
  AND precio = ?
  AND maquila = ?
```

los parámetro parametrizados han de ser pasados en el mismo orden en el que son definidos. Tu le pasas:

```
parameters = (new_name, estudios_clinicos, new_price, precio, new_price_maq, maquila)
```

lo que quedaría figuradamente como:

```
UPDATE price_list
SET estudios_clinicos = new_name,
    precio = estudios_clinicos,
    maquila = new_price
WHERE estudios_clinicos = precio
  AND precio = new_price_maq
  AND maquila = maquila
```

lo que se traduce en que la fila no es encontrada y por tanto no se actualiza nada. Debes pasar los parámetros en el orden correcto:

```
def edit_records(self, new_name, estudios_clinicos, new_price, precio, new_price_maq, maquila):
     query = 'UPDATE price_list SET estudios_clinicos = ?, precio = ?, maquila = ? WHERE estudios_clinicos = ? AND precio = ? AND maquila = ?'
     parameters = (new_name, new_price, new_price_maq, estudios_clinicos, precio, maquila)
     self.run_query(query, parameters)
     # ....
```

Dado que es de suponer que tu columna `estudios_clinicos` tiene valores no repetidos, bastaría con que buscaras solo por este valor.

Dos observaciones:

- No llames a  `self.edit_wind.mainloop()`, la ventana se muestra tras su inicialización sin más siempre que exista una ventana padre con su mainloop. Solo debes tener un ciclo principal por aplicación al mismo tiempo.
- Es lógico que en `edit_estudio` el contenido de los cuadros de texto aparezca vacío, llamas a `get` nada más instanciar la ventana. En ese punto el usuario no ha podido introducir nada todavía.

Comment: Amigo JFSevilla muchas gracias de nuevo por tu ayuda, entonces el problema estaba en que en vez de un ? Deberia de ir los nuevos datos tecleados por el usuario, y deben de llevar el orden en el que se estan guardando, ahora con respecto a al mainloop() entonces siempre que exista una ventana padre no será necesario sostenerla ya que el mismo padre la sostiene? Muchas gracias de nuevo y sobretodo por tomarte el tiempo!!!

Comment: No debes cambiar ningún ? ni modificar la query, solo debes pasar los parametros en el orden correcto,  en vez de `parameters = (new_name, estudios_clinicos, new_price, precio, new_price_maq, maquila)` debe ser `parameters = (new_name, new_price, new_price_maq, estudios_clinicos, precio, maquila)`. Es lo único que tienes que cambiar en principio. En cuanto a los segundo, efectivamente, siempre que exista un mainloop activo debe ser el el único encargado de procesar los eventos, ese mismo mainloop se encarga también de cualquier ventana hija que generes.

Comment: FJSevilla gracias de hecho cuando vi tu respuesta hice el cambio y funcionó correctamente :D con respecto a lo del mainloop tienes mucha razon no tiene caso que se mande a llamar si el padre lo esta sosteniendo, muy amable!!!!